# Как сделать , чтобы тест на javascript работал?

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Answer проверялся тест, и поле вопроса окрашивалось в зелёный цвет (если правильно) в красный (если не правильно)!

```js
var trueAnswers = [12, "голубое"]; //правильные ответы

var qp = document.querySelectorAll(".questionPole"); //для получения колличества вопросов, соотвественно итерраций цикла

var ab = document.getElementById("answerButton"); //кнопка

var mass = document.querySelectorAll(".some"); //


ab.onclick=function(){
  for(var i=0; i<qp.length; i++){
      for(var k=0; k<mass.length; k++){
        if(mass[k].checked && mass[k].value===trueAnswers[i]){
          mass[k].parentNode.style.backgroundColor="green"
        }else{
          mass[k].parentNode.style.backgroundColor="red"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="questionBlock0" class="questionBlock">
  <p class="questionPole">Сколько тебе лет?</p>
        <input class="some" type="radio" name="ast" value="12">12<br>
        <input class="some" type="radio" name="ast" value="34">34<br><br>
</div>

<div id="questionBlock1" class="questionBlock">
  <p class="questionPole">Какого цвета небо?</p>
        <input class="some" type="radio" name="ags" value="голубое">голубое<br>
        <input class="some" type="radio" name="ags" value="жёлтое">жёлтое<br><br>
</div>


<input id="answerButton" type="button" value="Answer">
```

Если у вас есть вариант решения данной проблемы (что проверка теста работает не корректно), пишите его в ответе, без использования сторонних библиотек, желательно исправив мой код!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var trueAnswers = [12, "голубое"]; 

var qp = document.querySelectorAll(".questionPole"); // Количество вопросов

var ab = document.getElementById("answerButton"); 

ab.onclick = function(){
  var check = document.querySelectorAll('.some:checked'); // Отмеченные радио
  // Если количество отмеченных меньше количества вопросов - делаем что-то.
  if( check.length < qp.length ){ alert('Вы не ответили на все вопросы!'); return; }
  //В данном случае, функция прерывает выполнение из-за return;

  // Кол-во вопросов и кол-во отмеченных - одинаковое, поэтому нужен только один цикл
  for( let i = 0; i < qp.length; i++ ){
    if( check[i].value == trueAnswers[i] ){ 
      /* Проверяем не на строгое ===, а просто на равенство ==, 
      потому что value получается в виде строки. А в массиве есть и число */
      qp[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
      qp[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="questionBlock0" class="questionBlock">
  <p class="questionPole">Сколько тебе лет?</p>
  <input class="some" type="radio" name="ast" value="12">12<br>
  <input class="some" type="radio" name="ast" value="34">34<br><br>
</div>

<div id="questionBlock1" class="questionBlock">
  <p class="questionPole">Какого цвета небо?</p>
  <input class="some" type="radio" name="ags" value="голубое">голубое<br>
  <input class="some" type="radio" name="ags" value="жёлтое">жёлтое<br><br>
</div>


<input id="answerButton" type="button" value="Answer">
```

P.s. смотрите в сторону тега `<label>` — если радио будут находится внутри него, пользователю приятнее будет переключать их) Чем пытаться попасть по маленькой кнопке.

P.s-2 вы запускали цикл среди всех радио, а потом проверяли на .checked и красили в зеленый... но на следующем круге оно всё равно находило следующее радио - проверяло, не checked - красило в красный.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, к сожалению осмыслить его пока нет времени, но как вернусь с работы, обязательно прочитаю! Спасибо

Comment: всё просто, и понятно, и работает, благодарю, проблема в том, что ваш код мне абсолютно понятен, но вот сам я почему-то не могу прийти к этому, видимо в виду недостатка времени. . . ещё раз спасибо, ты меня выручил очень!

Answer (score 0):

Не идеально, но у меня получилось что то такое

```js
var trueAnswers = {
  ast: 12, 
  ags: "голубое"
};

var elementsForm = document.forms['questions'].elements; // элементы формы
var ab = document.getElementById("form"); //форма

ab.onsubmit=function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  Object.values(elementsForm).forEach(function(elem) {
    if( elem.type !== 'submit' ) { // если не кнопка
      var blockQuestion = elem.parentElement.parentElement; // блок с вопросом
      if( !blockQuestion.classList.contains('question-checked') ) { // если он еще не проверен 
        var checkedElem = ab.querySelector('[name="' + elem.name + '"]:checked'); 
        if( checkedElem.value == trueAnswers[elem.name] ) { // проверяем
          blockQuestion.style.backgroundColor = '#3a3';
          blockQuestion.classList.add('question-checked');
        } else {
          blockQuestion.style.backgroundColor = '#a33';
          blockQuestion.classList.add('question-checked');
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<form id="form" name="questions">
  <div id="questionBlock0" class="questionBlock">
    <p class="questionPole">Сколько тебе лет?</p>
    <label><input class="some" type="radio" name="ast" value="12">12</label><br>
    <label><input class="some" type="radio" name="ast" value="34">34</label><br><br>
  </div>

  <div id="questionBlock1" class="questionBlock">
    <p class="questionPole">Какого цвета небо?</p>
    <label><input class="some" type="radio" name="ags" value="голубое">голубое</label><br>
    <label><input class="some" type="radio" name="ags" value="жёлтое">жёлтое</label><br><br>
  </div>


  <button id="answerButton" type="submit" value="Answer">Проверить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, к сожалению осмыслить его пока нет времени, но как вернусь с работы, обязательно прочитаю! Спасибо